# how to updating bottomSheet variable by updating a variable of it container

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I'm using a `bottomSheet` to display a list of offers, and this list coming from the main screen via a stream, My problem that I need to make the list of offers Updateable automatically when the user open the bottomSheet (display every new offer comes from the stream) but the bottomSheet takes the value of offer list once it opened, so I need to make the state of the bottomSheet changes when the offer list variable changes.

main.dart

```
    void onReceive(List<User> availableDrivers, List<Offers> submittedOffers,
          List<Booking> relativeBooking) {
        offers = submittedOffers;
        setState(() {
          offerItems = offers;
        });
        if (relativeBooking.isNotEmpty) launchReservationAction(relativeBooking[0]);
      }
    
      void startStreaming() {

    _clientService.streamTaxis(
      refresh: 5.seconds,
      onReceive: onReceive,
    );
  }

    ...
    Get.bottomSheet(OffersProposed( //Here I display the list
       offers: offers,
       confirmOffer: confirmOffer,
    ));
...
```

OffersProposed.dart

```
class OffersProposed extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Offers> offers;
  final Function(Offers) confirmOffer;
  final Function(bool) isOpen;

  const OffersProposed({Key key, this.offers, this.confirmOffer, this.isOpen})
      : super(key: key);
  @override
  _OffersProposedState createState() => _OffersProposedState();
}

class _OffersProposedState extends State<OffersProposed> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .8,
      width: Get.width,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(25), topRight: Radius.circular(25)),
        color: Color.fromRGBO(254, 255, 254, 1),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
              child: Text('Liste des offers',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black))),
          ListView.separated(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
              separatorBuilder: (context, i) => Divider(height: 2),
              itemCount: offerItems.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                final offer = offerItems[i]; //widget.offers[i];
                return Container(
                    decoration:
                        BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 6),
                    child: Card(
                         ....
                        ),
                          onTap: () async {
                            Get.back();
                            widget.confirmOffer(offer);
                          },
                        )));
              }),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I've tried to wrap the offer list in global variable but the interface doesn't updated (ofc because no setState method the update it. Also, I've tried ValueListenableBuilder.

Comment: Have you tried to pass your actual stream on your bottomsheet instead of passing `List<Offers>`?

Comment: I have to use my steam in main because I'm using it data there